# Make concrete implementation of factory/class combo where the concrete type is yet another generic

Tags: c#, generics, factory

I've a forwarder to forward generic messages and factory to create forwarder. Factory exists so it can hold the service to forward messages to but I removed it for sake of focused code.

```
public class MessageForwarder<TContent> : IMessageForwarder<TContent>
{
    public DeadLetterStoreForwarder()
    {
    }

    public async Task ForwardAsync(IContext<TContent> ctx)
    {
        // Work
    }
}
```

and factory

```
public class MessageForwarderFactory : IMessageForwarderFactory
{
    public MessageForwarderFactory()
    {
    }

    public IMessageForwarder<TContent> Create<TContent>()
    {
        return new MessageForwarder<TContent>();
    }
}
```

Interfaces match the only method in the above implementations.

```
public interface IMessageForwarder<TContent>
{
    Task ForwardAsync(IContext<TContent> ctx);
}

public interface IMessageForwarderFactory
{
    IMessageForwarder<TContent> Create<TContent>();
}
```

Now I want to make a variant of forwarder and forwarder factory that that will guarantee `TContent : MessagePayload<TEvent>` so that I can do slight manipulation of Payload in forwarder.

Attempts:
a) `public class DeadLetterStoreForwarder<TContent> : IMessageForwarder<MessagePayload<TContent>>` sets it right, but then I cannot change return type of `IMessageForwarderFactory.Create()` to `IMessageForwarder<MessagePayload<TContent>>` nor I can add generic constraint like `where TContent : MessagePayload<dynamic>` or anything similar.
b) `public class DeadLetterStoreForwarder<TContent, TEvent> : IMessageForwarder<TContent> where TContent : MessagePayload<TEvent>`, but then I cannot change return type of `IMessageForwarderFactory.Create()` to `IMessageForwarder<MessagePayload<TContent>>` again and `MessageForwarderFactory<TEvent>` will not make me utilize the factory and I will have to have factory for each type anyway.

Comment: "...will guarantee `TContent : MessagePayload<TEvent>`" What's `TEvent` here?

Comment: You seem to want the new variant of factory to implement `IMessageForwarderFactory`? That makes no sense. "A factory that produces a specific kind of thing" is not a kind of "factory that produces general things".

Comment: `TEvent` is something I dont care much about - but thats my generic thats always wrapped in `MessagePayload`. Im just forced to use the given interfaces, where I only pass `IMessageForwarderFactory` to external library. And I want to be able to manipulate ctx because in my case TContent is always MessagePayload<TEvent>.

Comment: when `TEvent` is `Foo` my `TContent` is `MessagePayload<Foo>`, when `TEvent` is `Bar` my `TContent` is `MessagePayload<Bar>`. I want to keep that genericity, but be able to work with `MessagePayload` structure.